# Cast DesktopWindowXamlSource to IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative fails with E_NOINTERFACE

Tags: com, winui-3, c++-winrt, windows-app-sdk, xaml-islands

I'm trying to use XAML Islands for WinUI 3 in a Win32 application.

After creating a new Win32 Desktop application from the File -> New Projet wizard, and:

1. Installing the latest versions of the Windows App SDK and CppWinRT NuGet packages (which are versions 1.4.231115000 and 2.0.230706.1 respectively),
2. Unloading the project, then adding `<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>` to the `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">` section of project file, and
3. Replacing the contents of the main .cpp file with the following:

```cpp
#include "framework.h"
#include "WinUI3XamlIslandsWin32.h"

#include <windows.ui.xaml.hosting.desktopwindowxamlsource.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Hosting.h>
#include <cassert>

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    winrt::init_apartment(winrt::apartment_type::single_threaded);
    auto dispatcherQueueController = winrt::Microsoft::UI::Dispatching::DispatcherQueueController::CreateOnCurrentThread();
    auto windowsXamlManager = winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Hosting::WindowsXamlManager::InitializeForCurrentThread();
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Hosting::DesktopWindowXamlSource desktopWindowXamlSource;
    auto interop = desktopWindowXamlSource.as<IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative>();
    assert(interop != nullptr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you run this program, it can successfully create the `DesktopWindowXamlSource`, but the line `desktopWindowXamlSource.as<IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative>()` fails with `E_NOINTERFACE`. Indeed, if you try `winrt::get_interfaces(desktopWindowXamlSource)` to list the interfaces the `DesktopWindowXamlSource` supports, it only lists:

- `IDesktopWindowXamlSource`
- `ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop`
- `IClosable`
- `IWeakReferenceSource`
- `ISupportErrorInfo`
- `IUnknown`
- `IInspectable`

Is there some extra step of setup necessary to allow the `DesktopWindowXamlSource` to be casted to the `IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative` interface?

I've created a sample project at https://github.com/litherum/WinUI3XamlIslandsWin32 demonstrating the problem.

Comment: According to the Doc:[IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.desktopwindowxamlsource/nn-windows-ui-xaml-hosting-desktopwindowxamlsource-idesktopwindowxamlsourcenative). I suggest you could try to use `windows.ui.xaml.hosting.desktopwindowxamlsource` instead of `microsoft.ui.xaml.hosting.desktopwindowxamlsource`. And I suggest you could refer to the Doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-standard-control-with-xaml-islands-cpp#use-the-xaml-hosting-api-to-host-a-winrt-xaml-control

Comment: That’s the class to use for WinUI 2. I trying to use WinUI 3.

Comment: `IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative` is for UWP only (everything in the `Windows.UI.Xaml` aka "WUX" is for UWP only, WinUI3 is in `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` namespace aka "MUX"). So it cannot work. What are you trying to do in the end?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like WinUI 3 changed how XAML Islands work.

| WinUI 2 | WinUI 3 |
| --- | --- |
| [`IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative::AttachToWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.desktopwindowxamlsource/nf-windows-ui-xaml-hosting-desktopwindowxamlsource-idesktopwindowxamlsourcenative-attachtowindow) | [`DesktopWindowXamlSource::Initialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.hosting.desktopwindowxamlsource.initialize?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#microsoft-ui-xaml-hosting-desktopwindowxamlsource-initialize(microsoft-ui-windowid)) |
| [`IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative::get_WindowHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.desktopwindowxamlsource/nf-windows-ui-xaml-hosting-desktopwindowxamlsource-idesktopwindowxamlsourcenative-get_windowhandle) | [`DesktopWindowXamlSource::SiteBridge()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.hosting.desktopwindowxamlsource.sitebridge?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#microsoft-ui-xaml-hosting-desktopwindowxamlsource-sitebridge).[`WindowID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.content.desktopsitebridge.windowid?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#microsoft-ui-content-desktopsitebridge-windowid) |
| [`IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative2::PreTranslateMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.desktopwindowxamlsource/nf-windows-ui-xaml-hosting-desktopwindowxamlsource-idesktopwindowxamlsourcenative2-pretranslatemessage) | [`ContentPreTranslateMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/win32/microsoft.ui.dispatching.interop/nf-microsoft-ui-dispatching-interop-contentpretranslatemessage) |

You can convert between `HWND`s and `WindowID`s by [`GetWindowFromWindowId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/win32/microsoft.ui.interop/nf-microsoft-ui-interop-getwindowfromwindowid) and [`GetWindowIdFromWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/win32/microsoft.ui.interop/nf-microsoft-ui-interop-getwindowidfromwindow).

Comment: More information is here: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/3978